# Loop through a column with coordinates in WKT

Tags: python, loops, coordinates

I got a problem with my Python script. I got open source data where I found out that the coordinates have an error.

```
POLYGON ((32563549.456 5934230.837,32563553.00....
```

This is my column where the coordinates which start with 32... are wrong. The 32 has to be deleted.
So I wrote a loop inside the column:

```
for x in Column:
    [x-320000000 if x>=3200000000 else x for x in Column]
    print(x)
```

But all the time I get an error:

```
'>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'.
```

Now I don't know how to proceed...

Answer (score 0):

assuming the OP didn't want to create a new list and want to use same list name so use this

```
 Column = [x for x in Column if str(x)[:2]!='32']
```

else use

```
 new_Column = [x for x in Column if str(x)[:2]!='32']
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but it somehow doesn´t work .. The 32 ist still there...i updated it and wrote it like in the 2nd example in a new list

Comment: this is just logic, iterate through each value , make it string and then check first 2 element are equal to '32'

Comment: Thanks, will try it!!